# Whitespace replace in C language

Tags: c

What is the right way to replace a white space with `_` in string passCode with 2 characters? 
In the end it should input/output: `(a )` → `(a_)`. Is there a way to do this using the isspace?

```
isspace(passCode[2]) == 0;
```

Comment: `isspace` can *test* for a space character (which would be useful when used with a loop here), but it is not capable of modifying the string itself.

Comment: Just a note: `isspace()` is a test for a _white-space_ character which in the default C locale is `' '`, `'\f'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'` or  `'\v'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the character is a space if yes, then replace it with `_`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  unsigned char str[]="a ";
  while (str[i])
  {
    if (isspace(str[i])) 
        str[i]='_';
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is dangerous. You shouldn't call `isspace` directly on a `char` (`char` type may be signed and thus sign-extend into unacceptable values for `isspace`).

Comment: @6502: So we should use `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Ani: yes... always use `isspace((unsigned char)s[i])` when checking data coming from a string or you may get a crash for non-ascii characters. It's ok also if you're passing an `int` you got for example from `fgetc` (by the way never store the result from `fgetc` into a `char` because the result can be a character - converted to unsigned - or `EOF` and if you store the result of `fgetc` into a `char` you will lose this distinction).

Comment: @6502 Agree about `isspace((unsigned char)s[i])`.  Curious though, have you ever come across a platform that `isspace((signed char)s[i])` provided undesired behavior?  If you did not, that does not negate the value of your comment though.

Comment: @chux: In addition to risking (in theory) a crash you're also getting the wrong answer. For example if your local code page is CP1251 and you check for `isalpha((char)255)` the answer is wrong (0) because that expands to -1 = EOF. The correct answer would be non-zero because 255 is letter "ja" (я) in russian and correctly `isalpha((unsigned char)255)` is non-zero. The fact that using `(char)x` with values outside the allowed range doesn't crash or do random things is just because implementers wanted to "help" old buggy code.

Comment: @6502 Agree with your comment.  ( I was familiar with those issues.)   Was looking for an example failure with `isspace()`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple manner for character substitution is simply to create a pointer to the string and then check each character in the string for value `x` and replace it with character `y` as you go. An example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    char passcode[] = "a ";
    char *ptr = passcode;

    while (*ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr == ' ')
            *ptr = '_';
        ptr++;
    }

    printf ("\n passcode: %s\n\n", passcode);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/chrep

 passcode: a_
```

Comment: Note: OP did ask about _white space_ vs. `' '`, though this method still mostly applies.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void replace_spaces(char *str)
 {
   while (*str)
   {
     if (*str == ' ')
       *str = '_';
     str++;
   }
 }

int main(int ac, int av)
{
  char *pass = 'pas te st';

  replace_spaces(pass);
  printf("%s\n", pass);
  return (0);
}
```

pass i now equal to 'pas_te_st'.

Comment: But how do you print the string now when you don't have a pointer to the beginning of the string anymore?

Comment: Note: OP did ask about _white space_ vs. `' '`, though this method still mostly applies.